# Autofill password on Login screen freezes and I don't know why

Tags: ios

When I try logging in to my app using a password manager like OnePassword or Lastpass, sometimes it works and I can log in to my app. Sometimes, it gets past the OnePassword login screen and then freezes. Other times, the keyboard is dismissed and the app is frozen until it's force closed.

I've referred to the following Apple documentation resources:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow

I don't have `applicationWillResignActive(_:)` or `applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)` methods implemented so I'm not sure how to proceed or think about solving this problem.

The only clue I have is the following message in the console: `Keyboard cannot present view controllers (attempted to present <UIKeyboardHiddenViewController_Autofill: 0x112a148a0>)`

I've looked around and can't seem to find any resources about that error message.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have experienced this freeze and seen the message too. Does it happen when the device isn’t attached to the debugger?

Comment: Are you doing this - passwordTextField.textContentType = .password

Comment: @Shesh Nath, I have set the textContentType.

Comment: @WarrenBurton, this happens when I am connected to my computer and when disconnected. It also happens when it's archived and run on my phone